# Make twilio leave a message after the beep

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, twilio

I am using Twilio to make calls to my clients to remind them of certain dates. Since some people dont pick up these calls, I would like to make my Twilio leave a voice message on their answering machines.

Is that possible? If yes how?

Thanks

Comment: Answering Machine Detection: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the RestAPI docs about the [`IfMachine` parameter](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making_calls#handling-outcomes-answering-machines):

> > If Twilio detects that a machine, not a human, has answered the call, Twilio will make a request to your application URL setting 'AnsweredBy' to 'machine'. The call flow will proceed as normal, and your application can choose to customize the content of the call for a recorded greeting. Twilio will wait until the familiar "BEEP" of an answering machine to begin executing your call flow, so the machine (or voicemail) will capture `<Play>` or `<Say>` content. Keep in mind that if a machine answers you'll want to avoid using `<Gather>` or `<Record>` because they require user input.

Also note:

> > Answering machine detection is an experimental feature, and support is limited.